# Are these four add-on wiring techniques all up to code?

Tags: electrical, home-automation, z-wave

I'm fixing some wiring mistakes in my house and installing some [GE Z-Wave Plus switches](https://byjasco.com/products/ge-z-wave-plus-wall-smart-dimmer) at the same time. Where there were 3- and 4-way switches I'm using the [GE Add-On switch](https://byjasco.com/products/ge-z-wave-wall-add-switch) to add additional control points.

Because the Dimmer switches have a nice blue LED to show when they are on/off, and the Add-On switches do NOT have this LED, I want to place the dimmers in certain locations, not always in the box where line enters or load leaves.

Are the following diagrams all 'legal' with respect to code and safety? The diagram on the bottom right is the one I'm most concerned with. Is it legal to have neutral enter the box from a different wiring path as line does, if they are on the same circuit?

[image: Diagram showing the four combinations of line entering and load exiting either the box where the main switch or add-on switch is.]

---

**UPDATED diagram**:

[image]

Comment: The bottom right example is a example of an incorrect circuit.

Comment: Current supplied by a cable must be returned by that cable. The total current in every cable must be zero. One can test this with an AC clamp meter.

Comment: @DanD. Thanks, that's what I was afraid of. (And by a "cable" you mean "a bundle of wires together", right? If I modified the bottom right to have four wires traveling together between those switches, and used one to carry neutral, that would be fine, yes?)

Comment: Also, @DanD. I'm happy to accept your comment as an answer if you post it as an answer.

Comment: By " cable" we mean what UL and NEC mean. A single sheath with markings indicating UL listing, type,size, stranding, number of conductors, brand, milepost, etc. You can modify your drawing to deploy /4 cable for instance.

Comment: Also why do you care whether the master or add-on is in one location or the other? They should have exactly the same controls/UI/UX.

Comment: Thanks, @Harper. I'm having trouble googling what a "/4 cable" is to get the common coloring right. Could you please link one? Regarding UX: see the question. The absence of LED light on the add-ons makes an unfortunate difference, albeit a small one. I chose the GE switches for other reasons before realizing this one issue, and at this point have about $3k worth of switches in hand and in wall. :) Since the "bottom right" scenario is impossible without pulling new wire, I'll just use the "top left" in its place, and damn the UX. Or I'll program all the LEDs to be always-off ;)

Comment: /4 is black white red blue.  It may be easier to find /2/2 cable, black white red white-red-stripe.  It has become a popular necessity owing to 404.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine ants climbing up a tree to harvest its fruit. It is a proper "tree topology" - **None of the branches ever touch each other**.  Ants are allowed to scurry up and down any branch in any order, but cannot leap or fall from branch to branch.

At *any point* on the tree, if we clamped an "ant current meter" around the branch, it would count exactly as many ants going up the branch as down.  Once past that point, ants might zig-zag up any number of sub-branches, but the ant must come back past this point at the end of the day.  144 ants go up past the point , 144 ants come back.  *Ant currents are equal*.  If there was a Residual Ant Fault Current Device, it would not trip.

If any of the branches touched each other, it would be possible for ants to go up branch 1 and come back on branch 2, making ant currents unequal on those branches.

So a "tree topology" is a pretty strong defense against the unequal currents problem.  How do you detect whether your diagram is a tree?  The "paint bucket" fill tool makes easy work of it. Trees don't enclose areas, so the paint should be able to reach all points (except between wires inside a cable.)

[image]

Nope, in #4, the wires enclose a space, so it's not a tree diagram, and currents are not equal because currents can encircle the space, imbalancing currents in every cable/raceway on each side of the space.

Answer (score 1):

In your original diagram, the bottom right configuration violates NEC 300.3(B)/310.10(H) due to the neutral current back from the switch taking a different route (cable or raceway) to get back to the panel than it got to you via the hot powering the switch.  Or in other words, if you clamp a clamp-on ammeter around the cable between the two boxes, it would read something other than 0, which points back to 300.3(B)/310.10(H) as another way of stating that part of Code is that "all currents in a cable must add up to 0, algebraically speaking (i.e. one direction is + and the other is -)".  Oops!

Your updated diagram fixes the bottom-right configuration, using a /4 cable to move the neutral into the same cable as the hots.